# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column '' cannot be null, getting data through an excel file

Tags: database, laravel

I;m using laravel and vue if that makes any difference. The data input I'm using if coming from an excel file, i can see the array of data when i inspect the website so i know the information is there, I'm trying to insert that info into the users table to do a massive user import option.

Basically how I'm doing it is, I'm receiving an excel that gets turned into an array, i separate that array into smaller arrays with only 5 users inside, and iterating thru those and saving that into the users table. The excel is full of info and there isn't anything that is empty.

My store method on the ImportUserController

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
       ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
       $users = $request->all();
       try {
           DB::beginTransaction();
           foreach ($users as $user) {
               $dbUser = $this->getUser($user['id']);
               Log::error($dbUser);
               $dbUser->name = $user['NAME'];
               $dbUser->user_name = $user['USERNAME'];
               $dbUser->email = $user['EMAIL'];
               $dbUser->last_name = $user['LAST-NAME'];
               $dbUser->password = $user['PASSWORD'];
               $this->isSet('USER-TYPE-ID', $user);
               $user_type_id = $this->getUserId($user['USER-TYPE-ID']);
               $dbUser->user_type_id = $user_type_id->id;
               $dbUser-> save();
           }
           DB::commit();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           DB::rollBack();
           throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error importando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
       }

   }
   private function isSet($field, $reqData)
   {
       if (!isset($reqData[$field])) {
           throw new HttpException(500, "Sucedio un error importando la información. No se encuenta la columna $field");
       }
   }

   private function getUserId($name)
   {
       $userId = UserType::where('name', $name)->first();
       if (empty($userId)) {
           $userId = new UserType();
           $userId->name = $name;
           $userId->save();
       }
       return $userId;
   }

   private function getUser($id)
   {
       $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
       if (empty($user)) {
           $user = new User();
       }
       return $user;
   }
```

this is the create users file

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('user_name')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->integer('user_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_types');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I'm not sure where the null is coming from? or why this is producing this error.

Comment: Can you `dd($user)` in foreach? Also in your model do you have `$fillable` fields?

Comment: which column is it that cant be null?

Comment: i tried to but nothing happened, in my model i have 
protected $fillable = [        'name', 'email', 'password', 'last_name', 'username', 'user_type_id']; 
Also i'm not the original author of a lot of this code, but i think none of the columns can be null

Comment: Are you posting to store method with axios? If so, dd() should be seen in the network tab in developer tools. Do a dd($users) before the loop and check if all the parameters are present.

Comment: @NancyGomez you said "but i think none of the columns can be null", ok, but wich one is the column that the error tells you cannot be null. it is clear that in the data that you are passing there one is null, but wich one

Comment: it says the column 'name', if i look in the network tab it says Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error, but again all the way on the bottom under Request Payload i can see the data and nothing is null

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i tried this but again nothing happens, anything else i can try?

Comment: but is the same error, refered to the same field/column 'name'?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ this is exactly what i get
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `user_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `user_type_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, $2y$10$KBRXNRlU3V1voqqn.GlL3.kPwt8JqTjxvfyOJXMUCyGZ/C1lEeAdu, ?, 2019-09-05 14:43:02, 2019-09-05 14:43:02)) []

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ thanks for all your help the error had something to do with the baseUrl, im using laravel and now its working!

Answer (score 0):

first print all of your input values then check that ,all values are coming correctly

Comment: the way im doing it is with steps, on the first step i upload the excel file, on the second step i get a preview of the info uploaded and on the final step i insert it into the database, so i know the data is there and is correct because i can see it before i do the final save into the db